# JavaFx logarithmic Axis in BarChart

Tags: javafx-2, logarithm

I need a logarithmic y-axis in a JavaFx BarChart. I tried use this
[implementation of a valueAxis](http://blog.dooapp.com/logarithmic-scale-strikes-back-in-javafx-20) .
That code seems to be correct and it works in a lineChart as a x-axis.
However it works not in a BarChart, there are simply no bars in the plot. The valueAxis should work in any kind of chart, so I think the BarChart is the problem. But I can not find the bug.

Here is my code, how I tested the chart:

```
LogarithmicAxis yAxis = new LogarithmicAxis();
yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(true);
yAxis.setVisible(true);
yAxis.setLabel("label");

chart = new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
chart.setAnimated(false);

Series<String, Number> aSeries = new Series<String, Number>();
aSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("test1", Math.log(90)));
aSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("test2", Math.log(100)));

answer = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
answer.addAll(aSeries);
chart.getData().addAll(answer);

chartFxPanel.setScene(new Scene(chart));
chart.layout();
```

Comment: I've filed an issue for investigation : http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28593, because it really looks like a bug in a bar chart

Comment: Whatever, if it is critical for you, you can try to download sources of openjfx, and try to debug that code of barchart...